# GPU Usage Metrics in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, gpu, wmic

Every time that I look at my task manager, I can see a percentage of GPU usage for all of my active processes.  I would like to display this percentage using javascript.  I can do this with CPU and RAM, as there are existing libraries, most of which use WMIC.  WMIC, as far as I can tell, does not have performance metrics for the graphics card.

Does anyone know what API's Microsoft uses to measure GPU performance?  I've been looking but can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

This link below shows some WMIC output from the graphics card, but nothing like what you are aiming for.

They also talk about the scriptomatic Script, but that is not working in my current Windows 10 version.

https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1181138

I hope this help you in finding some direction.
Ramon

Comment: I appreciate the link!  I will look into it, but I feel as if there should be a way given that, at least in task manager and things like the xbox game bar, you can monitor a GPU usage percentage.  I think that's probably in terms of VRAM or something.

Comment: Found this intriguing, I'll  be pending to see if someone else gives an answer.
Best of lucks.